# How to handle server side exceptions using jQuery load method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have a page named A.aspx that loads a B.aspx using the `load` jQuery method. Like this:

```
$('#doclist').load('Documents.aspx #div1', { idMsg: $(this).data('cid') }, function (response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
                var msg = "Error.";
                $('#doclist').html("<span>" + msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + ". " + "</span>");
            }
        });
```

This can handle exceptions such a `404` or `500 Internal server error`. The B page retrieve data from DataBase and a `DBException` is thrown but not catched by `load` jQuery method.

I don't do anything at code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response with `500 Internal server error` is the only thing script gets if there is no additional code o the server.

Consider returning JSON with data you need instead of HTML page. This way you can have custom errors as alternative result. I.e. for success `{"result": ....}` and in case of error: `{"error":"Nice error explanation"}`.

Comment: But my page has a complex listview and would be very dificult to return a json and map it to a table.

Comment: hope this link may help you http://www.rqna.net/qna/ttrvq-handle-session-timeout-in-generic-http-handler.html